# cloning a repository and refspecs

Tags: git

I've been playing with refspecs a bit to do some tracking of our software, and I'm a little confused. The refspecs I created live on our master repository, as I can fetch them, like this

```
git fetch origin '+refs/magic/*:refs/magic/*'
```

but they don't get fetched when I clone the repository. I can't find anything in the man page to indicate how I can do this.

I thought cloning a repository, well, cloned it. So do I really need to do a fetch after a clone, or is there some command line argument to clone I am missing? (and if so, what?)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the `--mirror` argument to `git clone`?

> --mirror
>              Set up a mirror of the source repository. This implies --bare.
>              Compared to --bare, --mirror not only maps local branches of the
>              source to local branches of the target, it maps all refs (including
>              remote-tracking branches, notes etc.) and sets up a refspec
>              configuration such that all these refs are overwritten by a git
>              remote update in the target repository.

Comment: yes, that's great for a --mirror clone. not so good for a normal clone